# Create a combined column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have input table as follows in Oracle.

[image: Input Table]

Please advise a SQL to obtain the output as follows:

[image: Output]

Here the requirement is to obtain "Combined" column which contains the column names if the corresponding value in the column is 1. Please see the above table for better understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the below query.

```
select column1, A, B, C, D, E, 
       rtrim(decode(A, 0,'','A, ') ||
       decode(A, 0,'','B, ') ||
       decode(A, 0,'','C, ') ||
       decode(A, 0,'','D, ') ||
       decode(A, 0,'','E'),',') combined
  from table_name;
```

Decode will match the value with 0, if its anything apart from 0, the column name will be concatenated.

RTRIM is for removing the last ',' in case the value in E is 0.

Comment: @Harsha - Can you mark the question as answered, if it worked for you.